# Randomising of browser profiles for Google Chrome in Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am wanting to randomise profiles for headless Chrome driver.  The below works however it seems to launch the same profile each time.
Code:

```
Profiles = []
for x in ['--profile-directory=Person 3, --profile-directory=Person 2']:
    indexes = [index for index in range(len(x))]
    shuffle(indexes)
     for index in indexes:
        dataDir = "--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\DAQ\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
        chrome_options1 = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options1.add_argument(dataDir)
        chrome_options1.add_argument(x)
        driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options1)
        driver1.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Your variable `index` is not used in the for loop.

Comment: You have a single item for x and a constant dataDir. What are you expecting to change for each new profile?